# When does degree 4 polynomial have 4 distinct real roots?

Tags: polynomials

Given

```
(x + 1)^4 - (a + 3)(x^2 + 2x) + a^2 + 3a + 1 == 0
```

find `a` such that this equation has 4 distinct real roots that form an arithmetic progression.

How can I do this?

Comment: Is this about the software package Mathematica?  What have you tried?

Answer (score 4):

```
Clear[a, f, x]

f[a_, x_] = (x + 1)^4 - (a + 3) (x^2 + 2 x) + a^2 + 3 a + 1;

Reduce[Unequal @@ (x /. Solve[f[a, x] == 0, x, Reals]), a, Reals]

(*  -(7/3) < a < -2 || -2 < a < -1  *)

Solve[Discriminant[f[a, x], x] == 0, a] // Union

(*  {{a -> -(7/3)}, {a -> -2}, {a -> -1}}  *)
```

There are two distinct roots for `a == -7/3`  or `a == -1`

```
Solve[f[-7/3, x] == 0, x, Reals]

(*  {{x -> 1/3 (-3 - Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 1/3 (-3 - Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 
   1/3 (-3 + Sqrt[3])}, {x -> 1/3 (-3 + Sqrt[3])}}  *)

Solve[f[-1, x] == 0, x, Reals]

(*  {{x -> -2}, {x -> -2}, {x -> 0}, {x -> 0}}  *)
```

and three distinct roots for `a == -2`

```
Solve[f[-2, x] == 0, x, Reals]

(*  {{x -> -2}, {x -> -1}, {x -> -1}, {x -> 0}}  *)
```

The rest of the interval `a == (-7/3, -1)` has four distinct roots

```
Manipulate[
 {xmin, xmax} = MinMax[roots = x /. NSolve[f[a, x] == 0, x, Reals]];
 Column[{
   roots,
   Plot[f[a, x], {x, 1.01 xmin, (1 + 0.1 Sign[xmax]) xmax},
    ImageSize -> Medium]
   }],
 {{a, -1.5}, -7/3, -1, Appearance -> "Labeled"}]
```

[image]

**EDIT:** Requiring that the roots are in an arithmetic progression (i.e., equally spaced)

```
sola = Assuming[-7/3 < a < -1,
  Solve[Equal @@ (Differences[
      x /. (Solve[f[a, x] == 0, x, Reals] // Simplify)]), a, Reals]]

(*  {{a -> -(29/13)}, {a -> -(11/7)}}  *)

roots = (x /. Solve[f[a /. #, x] == 0, x, Reals]) & /@ sola

(*  {{1/13 (-13 - 3 Sqrt[13]), 1/13 (-13 - Sqrt[13]), 1/13 (-13 + Sqrt[13]), 
  1/13 (-13 + 3 Sqrt[13])}, {1/7 (-7 - 3 Sqrt[7]), 1/7 (-7 - Sqrt[7]), 
  1/7 (-7 + Sqrt[7]), 1/7 (-7 + 3 Sqrt[7])}}  *)
```

Verifying that the roots are equally spaced in each case

```
Simplify[Differences /@ roots]

(*  {{2/Sqrt[13], 2/Sqrt[13], 2/Sqrt[13]}, {2/Sqrt[7], 2/Sqrt[7], 2/Sqrt[7]}}  *)
```

Comment: @dxiv - corrected. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Hint:  let $x+1=y\,$, then $x^2+2x=y^2-1\,$, and the equation can be written as:

$$0 = y^4 -(a+3)(y^2-1)+a^2+3a+1= y^4 -(a+3)y^2 + a^2+4a+4$$

The latter is a biquadratic, so the negative of each root is also a root, therefore the roots are real, distinct and in an arithmetic progression iff there exists a real $u \ne 0$ such that the $4$ roots in $y$ are $-3u, -u,u,3u\,$.

Then by Vieta's relations:

$$
\begin{cases}
\begin{align}
u^2 + 9 u^2 &= a+3 \\
9 u^4 &= a^2+4a+4
\end{align}
\end{cases}
$$

Eliminating $u$ between the above gives the equation in $a$ to be solved.